# What is the fuzz on my homemade granola?

Tags: granola

I made a double batch of my homemade granola and this morning I notice that the top of the granola was all fuzzy. I keep it in an airtight container. Does any one know what would cause it?

Comment: Sounds like mold.  You could have picked up mold spores in many places during the process.  For example, did you move the granola to the airtight containers with your hands?

Comment: A picture helps, and maybe the recipe you used as well. And definitely the amount of time it has been in that container. Please [edit] your question

Answer (score 2):

Did you put the granola away while it was still warm? The inside of the container may have collected moisture while the granola cooled to room temperature, causing mold to form.

Answer (score 0):

Toss the granola and sterilize or recycle the jar. Molds are from the fungi family and it is likely the spores either survived the baking process (you need heat to kill but too much burns the granola) or your batch got infected afterwards (the useful hands comment, or an opened or unclean container).

If doubling up the recipe gave less room on the baking sheets to spread out the batch that might be part of the problem. Make smaller batches and consume faster. If you are using a recipe and making substitutions the new items you are adding might be creating the problem. Many of the food preservation techniques for fighting bacteria (**low** pH, moisture, temperature and **high** salt or sugar) don't work for fighting molds.